# Store Image Clicks And Echo The Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Let's say I have 2 pages :**

`example.com/page1`
`example.com/page2`

**On each one of them there are 3 Images :**
When the user clicks on one of them, the next page loads. 
`img1.jpg`
`img2.jpg`
`img3.jpg`

The goal is, that I somehow pass the user selections,
so on page 3 ("results page") a link will be presented,
depending on what images user selected.

I assume it may look like this :

`example.com/?page1=img1?page2=img3`
(In case user selected img 1 on page 1 and img 3 on page 2)

Then, the string is analyzed , and if on page 1 img1 was
selected, and on page 2 img3 was selected specific URL will
be echoed.

Thank you !

Comment: What's the code you have tried and what's the problema with it? I can't understand what's your exact problem. If it's storing the variables during navigation or rendering the links in the end or what

Comment: Unfortunately my programming skills are not very good (to say the least). The code I wrote did not work obviously, and I think sharing it here will be funnier than a joke.Storing the variables during navigation is problematic, as well as echo the right link after analyzing the variables .

Answer (score 1):

Pass the link in `page1.php` as a link in the html:

```
<a href="page2.php?img=2" id="img2" ><img /></a>
```

Then, on the second page, get the img and append it to every link

```
<a href="page3.php?img2=2&<?php echo "img1=" . $_GET['img']  ?>";
```

Comment: Thank you **very** much, this helped me a lot. I appreciate your help. Can someone now help me with the final stage - where the variables are analyzed, and a link is echo depending on the values?

Comment: may be like this `if($_GET['page1']=='img1' && $_GET['page2']=='img3'){echo 'speacial link';}` @user3070303

Comment: And if let's say the base URL stays the same (example.com), and I want that if on page 1 img1 was selected, "ab" ending will be echoed at the end of the link, and if on page 2 img 3 was selected "rt" ending will be echoed at the end of link. So in case of example.com/?page1=img1?page2=img3, the final link will be example.com/abrt